# substring-after and substring-before with an element instead of a string

Tags: xml, xslt

is it possible to use substring-before and substring-after with an element as a selector? If not, how would you do it?

If I have this snippet for example,

```
<root>
    <element>This is an example. Some text here | and some text there</element>
</root>
```

I could use substring-before or substring-after and the pipe | to get the text on the left or right side

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="root">          
    <element><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(element, '|')"/></element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element1>This is an example. Some text here </element1>
```

But how could I do that with an element dividing the text, like a lb or alt?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>This is an example. Some text here <alt type="divider"/> and some text there</element>
</root>
```

I was thinking about something with sibling, but I dont want to return a element but the string. So I can't really wrap my head around it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't use `text()` with a selector axis?

Comment: "*how could I do that with an element dividing the text*" An element never "divides text". What you show are three independent, sibling nodes: a text node, an element node, and another text node.

Comment: You've classically phrased the question the wrong way: rather than asking "how can I achieve X", you have asked "can I use a double-ended hammer?"; this leaves us to study the post to discover what result you want, and advise you that double-ended hammers are not the way to go. In fact, the way you have phrased the question suggests you are thinking of the XML document as a string of content with interleaved markup, and not as a tree of nodes. You need to change that thinking!

Answer (score 0):

The path `/root/element/text()[1]` would give you the text node before the `alt` element, the path `/root/element/text()[2]` the text node after the `alt` element, this assumes you know there is such an element and you have two text nodes separated by an element. The `value-of` outputs the string value of a node anyway, you never output a node itself with `value-of`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this XPath expression

```
/root/element/text()[not(preceding-sibling::alt)]
```

selects the text *before* the `alt`,

```
 and some text there
```

and his XPath expression,

```
/root/element/text()[not(following-sibling::alt)]
```

selects the text *after* the `alt`:

```
 and some text there
```